# Is there a way to know if a UIViewController has been presented and dismissed modally ?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to know if a UIViewController has been presented and dismissed modally ?

Something like:

- hasBeenPresentedModally
- hasBeenDismissedModally

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing built in, but a view controller could, upon receiving `viewDidAppear` and/or `viewWillDisappear` check whether it has a `parentViewController`, since per [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/parentViewController) (emphasis added):

> Parent view controllers are relevant in navigation, tab bar, and modal
>   view controller hierarchies. In each of these hierarchies, the parent
>   is the object responsible for displaying the current view controller.
>   **If you are using a view controller as a standalone object—that is, not
>   as part of a view controller hierarchy—the value in this property is
>   nil.**

If it has then it can set suitable flags for future reference.

Note that being presented modally is different from being truly modal. For example, on an iPad you might put one controller inside a `UIPopoverController`, so that controller isn't presented modally, but then it might modally present another controller on top of itself. So the second controller is presented modally but isn't itself a modal dialogue because — if the program is otherwise set up suitably — the user can just ignore the popover entirely.

Comment: `viewWillDisappear` is too early; `viewDidDisappear` is appropriate for checking if the parent was nulled out, e.g. after popping off a nav stack.

Answer (score 6):

Check if your UIViewController's `parentViewController` property is `nil` or not.
If the property is `nil` then it's dismissed otherwise it's presented.

NOTE: UITableViewController's childViewController's `parentViewController` property would also be not `nil`, you should also make sure the parentViewController is not UITableViewController.